# Switching left/right audio with a DPDT relay

Tags: arduino, audio, relay, dpdt

Is it possible to switch the left and right channels of the 3.5mm inputs below to the output with a AZ850P2-5 DPDT relay (given a 5V power source)? I have a hard time reading the pinout of the relay. How would one go about wiring this circuit, and connecting an Arduino to control it?

[image]

I have previously used a 2-channel relay module, but I am hoping for something more compact.

Comment: It's possible, yes. If you edit your diagram to include wire numbers or something similar, then answers can more directly reference how it should be hooked up.

Answer (score 3):

The AZ850P2-5 is a two-coil bistable relay.

You apply a pulse between pin 1 and 5 to "set" the contacts, and between pin 10 and 6 to "reset" the contacts (5 volts, pin 1 and 10 positive). The contacts will stay in the last driven position - there is no need to apply power to hold the contacts in position.

When the relay is "reset" there are connections between pins 3 and 2, and between 8 and 9.  When "set", there are connections between 3 and 4, and between 8 and 7.